# PayPal IPN not doing ANYTHING

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on a problem I've been trying to figure out for the past two days. I've read and re-read the PayPal documentation and it doesn't provide any help or insights whatsoever.

This is the IPN listener I'm using, this is the example script PayPal provides:

```
    <?php
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    if ($payment_status == 'Completed') {
    include_once('update.php');     
    }

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

What am I missing? All I want to do is verify that the payment is complete and then include PHP from another file. The IPN History in the sandbox account is showing that the IPN requests are being sent and are receiving HTTP 200 response.

payment_status is also definitely being sent as it's also shown in the IPN history.

Any help or pointers to some IPN tutorials that actually make sense, would be massively appreciated!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the problem in your IPN ? Is your IPN being called or not ? If yes, is your IPN executed entirely ? Or does it stop in the middle ?

Comment: I have no idea, I have no way to debug what's going on. The IPN must be being called, because the IPNs are showing as SENT in the IPN History of my Sandbox account - with a HTTP 200 response.

Comment: Sure you do, `error_log`, you've already got some instances of it in your code. Just put in more, put one at the top of the page to make sure it's running the script and then take it from there. Alternatively you can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to simulate an IPN notification, just copy the IPN content from PayPal and you can send and see the response as many times as you need to.

Comment: Where would this error_log be? I can't seem to find it on my server.

Comment: If you look into your paypal IPN history (https://www.paypal.com/?cmd=_display-ipns-history), you click on the "message number" of your IPN, then you check if it's really a HTTP 200 result, if the notification URL is the good one, and then as Styphon said, add some logs. You can check into your access log too..

Comment: change `define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");` by `define("LOG_FILE", dirname(__FILE__)."/ipn.log");`, the log will be in the same folder than your IPN php file.

Comment: Julqas, the result is definitely HTTP 200.

Comment: Just tried the postman method, still nothing. Also there is no log file being created!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

PayPal required the connection to be SSL/Signed using the cacert.pem file. You can turn this off by changing

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);`

To

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Thanks for your help guys!